# Could not launch app, "process launch failed: Disabled"

Tags: ios, xcode

xcode give me this error message when i run my project Try on ios device in my case mini ipad,

i am using code signe development

the device appers in the run list

the project setting is valid

the error :

error: failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/389D3AA9-DC56-4FD5-91CD-17C51C4E064A/Try.app' -- process launch failed: Disabled

any help please ?

Comment: have you tried to _clean_ the project?

Comment: yes i tried but nothing shanged

Comment: maybe it is silly, but have you enrolled the iOS Developer Program? have your iPad _trusted_ in your computer?

Comment: yes it is trusted in my computer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had this same problem/error but it wasn't a provisioning profile issue. Unchecking the "Launch due to a background fetch event" box in the Edit Scheme menu fixed it for me.

[image: uncheck this box]

Step-by-step:

1. In Xcode, click the button that includes your app's name that is to the immediate right of the Stop button
2. Click "Edit Scheme..." in the dropdown menu
3. Make sure "Run" is selected on the left and "Options" is selected at the top
4. The Background Fetch box will be in the middle of the view

As Jesuslg123 mentioned below, it's reasonable to have this box checked if you wish to test your app's background functionality. Most users experiencing this problem however have likely checked it erroneously or have since disabled the corresponding background features for their app and forgotten to uncheck it (such as myself).

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Please accept my response as the answer to your question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for your valuable time to the answer , it helps me :)

Comment: You don't need to disable/uncheck the "Launch due to a background fetch event". If you don't need background fetch, go head and disable it, but it is completely normal need to enable that for testing purposes. If you have enabled the option  "Launch due to a background fetch event", and you have the error, probably is because you have not enabled the capability. Go to your app target -> "Capabilities" -> Enable "Background modes" -> Check "Background fetch" option.
It's worked for me. I hope is useful.

Comment: does not work for me, cos it already unchecked. But when I check it I have the "process launch failed: Disabled" without start app...

Comment: @WINSergey are you receiving the "process launch failed: Disabled" message when the box is unchecked?

Comment: @NathanHosselton no, in checked case

Comment: @WINSergey then your app is failing to launch for other reasons.

Comment: After reinstall OSX and un-check this flag app starts on device but not allow me to debug coz debug session disconnect in 3-5 sec. @NathanHosselton any ideas?

Comment: Whoa! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to debug background fetch, please, don't forget to enable it in

`Target -> Capabilities -> Background Modes`

Answer (score 0):

**i send the error to apple support and this their response**

Thank you for contacting Apple Worldwide Developer Technical Support. I am responding to let you know that I have received your request for technical assistance.

The above message implies that your app was signed with a Distribution Provisioning profile. Please run the following command on your binary in the Terminal application to determine whether your 
app was built with a Development or Distribution profile:
codesign -dv .app

This command will output information about your binary. Your binary was built with a developer profile if the Authority line is set as follows:
             Authority=iPhone Developer: xxxxxxxx (xxxxxx)

App built with a developer profile

```
codesign -dvvv /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickContacts-                       eqjxksovflunlhgkarzfztmivkbv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/QuickContacts.app 
Executable=/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QuickContacts-          eqjxksovflunlhgkarzfztmivkbv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/QuickContacts.app/QuickContacts
Identifier=com.example.apple-samplecode.ContainingApp
Format=bundle with Mach-O universal (armv7 (16777228:0))
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=526 flags=0x0(none) hashes=16+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=99a7c9dbbbfec50a12db9c17a72d208828cc1b14
Signature size=4332
Authority=iPhone Developer: xxxxxxxx (xxxxxx)
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=Nov 17, 2014, 10:52:45 AM
Info.plist entries=30
TeamIdentifier=4C89638E89
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=15
Internal requirements count=1 size=204
```

App built with a distribution profile

```
codesign -dvvv /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-11-17/QuickContacts\ 11-17-    14\,\ 10.56\ AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/QuickContacts.app 
Executable=/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2014-11-17/QuickContacts 11-17-14,     10.56 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/QuickContacts.app/QuickContacts
Identifier=com.example.apple-samplecode.ContainingApp
Format=bundle with Mach-O universal (armv7 (16777228:0))
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=486 flags=0x0(none) hashes=14+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha1 size=20
CDHash=054d2ece4a0babeaf3dc53ddd2c3685173c716ec
Signature size=4335
Authority=iPhone Distribution: xxxxxx (xxxxxx)
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=Nov 17, 2014, 10:56:09 AM
Info.plist entries=30
TeamIdentifier=4C89638E89
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=16
Internal requirements count=1 size=208
```

Answer (score 0):

**Product-->Scheme-->Edit Scheme-->Run-->Options**

To ensure that the '**Background Fetch(Launch due to a background fetch event)**'box is **unchecked**;

It works for me!